# Mongoose - can't access createdAt

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I'm creating a NestJs application using Mongoose, I'm currently having a problem trying to access createdAt even though I have set timestamps to true, my code is below.

product.schema.ts

```
@Schema({timestamps: true})
export class Product extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name!: string;
}
```

product.service.ts

```
public async getProduct(name: string): Promise<void> {
    const existingProduct = await this.productModel.findOne({ name });

    if (!existingProduct) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    existingProduct.createdAt //Property 'createdAt' does not exist on type 'Product'
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just because you set `timestamps: true` doesn't mean that typescript understands that those fields should exist. You need to add them to the class, but without the `@Prop()` decorator, so that typescript knows the fields exist, but Nest doesn't try to re-create the fields for you.

Comment: So do you mean I should use a constructor in the class?

Comment: I mean you just need to add the two properties to your `Product` class without the `@Prop()` decorator